# Why doesn't LiteIDE build the go file that is selected/highlighted?

Tags: go, liteide

In LiteIDE, when I select a file, then choose "install" from the "build" menu, a different file is built than the one selected. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, you have to double-click the selected file, so that the go code is visible in the code editor. Only after doing this do commands such as "build" and "install" operate on the expected file. So although the file may be appear to be selected on the left hand navigation, unless it is actually loaded in the code editor it is not selected.